# FF Cannot select item from dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, dropdown

There is a navbar which shows on mouse hover (`hoverStateIn()` event), disappears on mouse leave (`hoverStateOut()` event):

**HTML**

```
<div id="shownav" (mouseenter)="hoverStateIn()" (mouseleave)="hoverStateOut()">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md jh-navbar" *ngIf="isHover">
    ...
    </nav>
</div>
```

**Typescript:**

```
hoverStateIn() {

    this.isHover = true;

    document.getElementById("main-container").style.paddingTop = "70px";
    document.getElementById("styleSelector").style.top = "95px";
}

hoverStateOut() {
    this.isHover = false;

    document.getElementById("main-container").style.paddingTop = "0";
    document.getElementById("styleSelector").style.top = "25px";
}
```

Navbar contains a dropdown and when trying to choose an item from a dropdown,  navbar disappears (the problem exist just in Firefox).

It seems dropdown control in FF loses focus and `hoverStateOut()` triggers.
How to fix this?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s22bjy)